# How To Filter AutocompleteBox Input from Another Column in Lightswitch 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to provide users with autocompletebox input control with items taken from database.

[image: the autocompletebox in design screen]

However, I'm stuck with how to change the strings filter to be referred from another column, instead of primary key.

The image below shows an example where I can filter input with primary key, but unable to  do so using device name.
[image: autocomplete box only refers to primary key]

[image: autocomplete box does not refer to other column]
Users rarely filter  primary key. They will likely search device names since it's easier.

Thank you so much for your help.

--
Here's the behind code of the screen

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Extensions;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class FormDeviceLending
    {

        private ModalWindowHelper modalAddLendingWindowHelper;
        private ModalWindowHelper modalEditLendingWindowHelper;

        partial void FormDeviceLending_InitializeDataWorkspace(System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataService> saveChangesTo)
        {
            modalAddLendingWindowHelper = new ModalWindowHelper(this.DeviceLendings, "ModalAddLending");
            modalEditLendingWindowHelper = new ModalWindowHelper(this.DeviceLendings, "ModalEditLending");
        }

        partial void FormDeviceLending_Created()
        {
            modalAddLendingWindowHelper.Initialise();
            modalEditLendingWindowHelper.Initialise();


        }

        partial void DeviceLendingsAddAndEditNew_Execute()
        {
            modalAddLendingWindowHelper.AddEntity();
        }


        partial void AddLendingOK_Execute()
        {
            modalAddLendingWindowHelper.DialogOk();


        }

        partial void AddLendingCancel_Execute()
        {
            modalAddLendingWindowHelper.DialogCancel();

        }

        partial void EditLendingOK_Execute()
        {
            modalEditLendingWindowHelper.DialogOk();

        }

        partial void EditLendingCancel_Execute()
        {
            modalEditLendingWindowHelper.DialogCancel();

        }


        partial void DeviceLendingsEditSelected_Execute()
        {
            modalEditLendingWindowHelper.ViewEntity();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code buddy.. With just images we cannot know anything about your application..

Comment: oh alright, Ill post the behind codes